# Get Date format from Data

Tags: python, date, datetime, format

My input source has date present in all possible formats, I want to write generic code to decode all the possible dates that might be present.
I am trying to fetch the date format from data itself, is it possible to get the format from data?

I tried writing some if conditions to get the format, but my confusion is around dates like 2019-06-07 - it can be interpreted as 2019 June or 2019 July as well.

In the code snip below if we are able to fetch dateformat from data itself, the problem will be solved

```
import datetime


dateformat='%Y/%m/%d'

try:
    pk = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018/06/13', dateformat)
except:
    pk = False

if pk:
    print(pk.date())
else:
    print('issue with date')
```

Comment: `2019-06-07` is the seventh of June. Someone using that to mean the sixth of July is simply wrong. One of the advantages of year-first date format is that no-one should be using `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: ***I want to write generic code to decode all the possible dates that might be present*** - Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this 100% correctly: the example you gave *is* ambiguous, but YYYY-DD-MM would be very unlikely. Something like 01/02/2019 means 1st of February in the UK and January 2nd in the US, and there's no way to tell which without metadata.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. That was my initial assumption regarding this well. We won't be able to guess the format given that there could be many possibilities. Can we not extract a pattern from entire data and whatever occurs the majority of times will be treated as the format for all. Since I will have the same format in a single file, only different files will have different formats

Answer (score 0):

Try `dateutil` its a great library for parse different type of date and time formats

```
from dateutil import parser
print parser.parse('2018/06/13')
```

Try to parse any datetime format you want.